# Spark How to perform a groupBy aggregation in withColumn function using expr

Tags: sql, apache-spark, data-manipulation

How do I perform a distinct count aggregation on a DataFrame using the withColumn() function and expr() function? The following command doesn't work:

`df.withColumn("days", expr("count(distinct date) group by url"))`

What is the correct method to do a groupBy in the expr() function ?

Comment: No, you can't. `expr`  takes a string expression of Column.

Comment: @blackbishop What comprises of a string expression of a Column and what all expressions are allowed in expr() ?

Comment: Well, you can use literal values (e.g. `expr("1")`, `expr("'v'")`), column names (e.g. `expr("date")`), or return value of any [sql function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/) (e.g. `expr("to_date(date)")`)

Comment: @blackbishop Why can't I use groupBy like I use window functions? `count(date) over (partition by url)`